# Attempting to pin a message while being suspended RO throws a message telling me that I'm not RO

Tags: bug, status-declined, chat, account-suspension

[image]

The message is just saying I am not a RO, if I try to pin being suspended.

But since when being suspended disqualify me from being a RO? I get still listed as RO in the ROs list.

Comment: Seems fair, imho, a privilege that you'll have to re-earn

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's just say your room ownership is in… wait for it … suspension for that time. The precise phrasing would be

> Only users with room ownership *permissions* can pin messages

and even users who are listed as room owners don't technically have room ownership permissions while suspended.

But making this and similar messages more complicated just to accommodate suspended users is not really something I want to spend time on. Suspended users have to live with the fact that their status is an edge case.

Comment: Eh, don't be lazy :D